# PC randomly boots with a black screen

Tags: boot, windows-11, black-screen-of-death

My PC randomly boots into a black screen.

I hear the windows startup sound, but I dont see anything - the monitor is turned on and it seems it receives a signal, just a black signal (i.e. monitor is not on standby)

When I reset during boot, it seems the boot troubleshoot menu pops up i think, because when I press Enter/Space it plays the windows startup sound after a few seconds, but still a black screen.

When I cut the power during boot and wait like half an hour, I have a screen again and i see the boot troubleshoot menu. Starting windows works but the Display Driver is disabled.
I can then re-enable the driver via Device Manager and it works again.

I have a
AMD Ryzen 9 5900X
AMD Radeon RX 7900 XT
Windows 11 Pro

I have updated the drivers multiple times already but occasionally I receive a black screen like mentioned.

Comment: Have you considered the possability the problem is casued by hardware not software?